# How to create an 'All' option in Access VBA forms to be passed as a query parameter?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a table named Persons such as :

```
     ID        Name

     1         John
     2         Jerry
     3         Jack
```

I have set up a form named Form1 with a Combo Box named Combo1 .

Combo1 has 3 values-

```
    1
    2
    3
    All
```

Then I set up the following query:

```
    Select * From Persons WHERE Persons.ID = (Forms![Form1]![Combo1]);
```

The query works fine when 1,2 or 3 are selected in the Combo Box but I can't figure out how to make it work to select all the records when the user selects 'All'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why VBA is required.  Seems to me you can get what you need with only a query ...

```sql
Select *
From Persons
WHERE
        Persons.ID = Forms![Form1]![Combo1]
    OR Forms![Form1]![Combo1] = 'All';
```

When *All* is selected in the combo box, the condition `Forms![Form1]![Combo1] = 'All'` will be True for all rows in the table.  So none are excluded from the query's result set.

When anything other than *All* is selected in the combo box, the query will return only rows whose `ID` value matches the combo box value.

Comment: Is there any way to do it If I am using two parameters? For example if I am using two parameters for the queries such as:

Comment: How do I make it work for multiple parameters?

I modified the table to look like following:

ID                Name
1                 John
1                 Jerry
2                 Jack
2                 Ben
3                 Bill

I added another Combo Box named Combo2. Combo2 has three values - John, Jerry, All

And I modified the query to the following:

Select *
From Persons
WHERE
        Persons.ID > Forms![Form1]![Combo1]
  AND Persons.Name = Forms![Form1]![Combo2]

How can I make it work so that the user can view All Names for ID's greater than 1?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking now.  Consider submitting a new question.

Comment: You can achieve the same as the original answer with: `SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Forms![Form1]![Combo1] IN ('All', Persons.ID)` - this might give more flexibility for multiple parameters

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your Combo1 looks like now?
Are you asking to show all entries with ID > 1 or all entries > than the ID selected in Combo1 - and do you still have the ALL option in Combo 1?

If you're just asking your last question:

> How can I make it work so that the user can view All Names for ID's
>   greater than 1?

Then you can probably use

```
Select * From Persons WHERE Persons.ID > 1 
AND (Persons.Name = Forms![Form1]![Combo2] OR Forms![Form1]![Combo2] = 'All');
```

But right now I think you have everyone confused with what you want. Hope I guessed right and put you on the correct path